# Search strings inside various test files with cmd

Tags: windows-7, search, cmd.exe

I have multiple text files containing thousands of emails for marketing. These files contain also other information than these mails. Is there any way using `cmd` to select all these files together filter these emails specifically and output them to an Excel document?

Answer (score 1):

The standard utility is "find", the syntax and available options is shown by:

```
C:\> find /?
```

Example session at the command prompt:

```
cd /d C:\
dir /s /b >FILES.txt
find /i "calc" FILES.txt
...
```

... is likely to display the path and filename of the Windows Calculator EXE file.

If you wish to look up more than one search term, then use pipes; as in:

```
find /i "text for first coarse search" FILES.txt | find /i "fine tune it" | find /i "yet more fine tuned"
```

If you want even more options, try to find a "grep" utility for Windows, but then you will need to understand "regular expressions" - as always; as handiness increases the complexity is prone to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my [jgrep.bat](https://gist.github.com/krowe/da2a6b021ac891f8e3be) script to be capable of this with the new `-o` flag. To use it for your problem, you'll want to copy the script to the folder where you have these files, then create a new file and add this to it:

```
@echo off
cd "%~dp0"
FOR /R . %%G IN (*.txt) DO @jgrep.bat -o "[A-Za-z0-9/-_.]+@[A-Za-z0-9\-_.]+" < "%%G"
pause
```

This should do what you want. Just copy those results to your Excel spreadsheet.